# What is the highest number of picks a team has had in the draft?

Tags: trivia, american-football, nfl, draft

I was looking at the draft from 2012 and noticed that the 49ers had made a lot of trades to acquire more picks for the 2013 draft. This led me to wonder about trades and the number of draft picks teams have had.

What team has had the highest number of draft picks in a single year, what year was it, and how many picks did they have? Please exclude supplemental draft picks from any answer.

**Edit:**
I didn't realize how many more rounds there used to be in the draft. I'm curious about the seven round format that is currently used.

Comment: Being facetious, I would say the NE Patriots, cause it seems they pull off having two first round draft picks a year.

Comment: I know the Philadelphia Eagles had 13 draft picks in the 2011 draft though they only ended up keeping 11 of them because they traded up. That is the highest amount I know of as a quick Google search didnt produce results

Comment: Does the format of the draft matter? For instance, in the late 60's/early 70's, the NFL conducted drafts with 17 rounds, quite a few more than the current 7 round format.

Comment: I'd be more interested in the seven round format, but that is a good point. I didn't realize drafts had that many more rounds in the past.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Update (2020 Draft):**

In 2020, the Minnesota Vikings had 15 picks, giving them the record for most picks since the draft was limited to 7 rounds. This also gave them the most picks since the 2002 realignment and the most picks since the draft became a 3-day event.

---

**Update (2016 Draft):**

In 2016, the Cleveland Browns had 14 picks, tying the 1997 Miami Dolphins for most picks since the draft was limited to 7 rounds. This also gave them the most picks since the 2002 realignment and the most picks since the draft became a 3-day event.

---

I went and looked at all of the draft picks broken down by team [here](http://www.drafthistory.com/). It looks like the 7-round format started in 1994, although I've been having some serious problems trying to confirm this. I looked through the number of picks each team had and found the following:

1. The highest number of draft picks by any team since the 7-round format started was by the Miami Dolphins. They used 14 total picks in 1997.
2. Since the league was realigned into 8 divisions split between two conferences in 2002, two teams have had 13 picks: the 2010 Philadelphia Eagles and the 2004 Tennessee Titans.
3. The 2010 Eagles also have the highest number of picks since the draft became a 3-day event in 2010.
4. The team slated to have the most draft picks in 2013 is the San Francisco 49ers with 11.

I also took this opportunity to see which teams had the fewest number of picks. The 1999 New Orleans Saints had one draft pick. Apparently, [they traded all six of their draft picks to the Redskins in order to get RB Ricky Williams with the fifth overall pick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1999_NFL_Draft).

Comment: Per https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1994_NFL_Draft it claims that 94 was the first time it was limited to 7 rounds.  The 93 draft had 8 rounds so it seems to be true.